# Erro ao usar uma static final String para construir uma query SQL

Tags: java, android, sql

Boa noite pessoa, andei pesquisando por ai e sei que da para fazer o CRUD organizado... sei que o programador cria uma classe com as strings, deixando por exemplo `public static final String NAME_TABLE = "nome";` e assim por diante, depois la na classe DBHelper você chama o **NAME_TABLE** - `"CREATE TABLE " + NAME_TABLE + "....`

Isso é feito para não ter erro de digitação no futuro, pois quando precisar fazer um insert ou ou update voce so chama o nome da coluna ou tabela que precisa... em resumo fiz uma classe string e outra DBHelper

ao fazer a listagem dos meus dados na activity ele me apresenta um erro dizendo

**Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FROM": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT FROM resultado**

Não sei como posso prossegui com essa organização, pois não sei como chama-la certa, ao inves de colcoar `NAME_TABLE` coloquei `getNameTable()` e parece que ele não esta reconhecendo

class strings

```
package DataModel;

public class DataModel {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "Resultados";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "resultado";
    private static final String ID = "id";
    private static final String TIME_CASA = "TimeCasa";
    private static final String TIME_FORA = "TimeFora";

    public static String getDbName() {
        return DB_NAME;
    }

    public static String getTableName() {
        return TABLE_NAME;
    }

    public static String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public static String getTimeCasa() {
        return TIME_CASA;
    }

    public static String getTimeFora() {
        return TIME_FORA;
    }
}
```

DBHelper

```
package Base;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import DataModel.DataModel;

import static DataModel.DataModel.getGolsCasa;
import static DataModel.DataModel.getGolsFora;
import static DataModel.DataModel.getID;
import static DataModel.DataModel.getTableName;


public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String NAME_BASE = "Resultados";
    private static final int VERSION_BASE = 1;

    public DbHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, NAME_BASE, null, VERSION_BASE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sqlCreateTableResultado = "CREATE TABLE"+ getTableName() +"("
                + getID()+ "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + getGolsCasa()+ "TEXT,"
                + getGolsFora()+"TimeFora TEXT,"
                + "JogadoresCasa TEXT,"
                + "JogadoresFora TEXT,"
                + "GolsCasa INTEGER,"
                + "CartaoVermelho INTEGER,"
                + "CartaoAmarelo INTEGER,"
                + "GolsFora INTEGER" + ")";

        db.execSQL(sqlCreateTableResultado);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String sqlDropTableResultado = "DROP TABLE " + getTableName();

        db.execSQL(sqlDropTableResultado);

        onCreate(db);

    }

public List<Esporte> selectTodosResult() {
        List<Esporte> listResult = new ArrayList<Esporte>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        String sqlSelectTodosResult = "SELECT FROM " + getTableName();

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sqlSelectTodosResult, null);

        try {
            if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                c.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    Esporte inserirBanco = new Esporte();
                    inserirBanco.setId(c.getInt(0));
                    inserirBanco.setNomeTimeUm(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TimeCasa")));
                    inserirBanco.setNomeTimeDois(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TimeFora")));

                    listResult.add(inserirBanco);

                } while (c.moveToNext());
}
        }
    }catch (SQLException or){
        or.printStackTrace();
    }
    db.close();
    return listResult;
}
```

Alguém conseguiria me ajudar passando alguma dica ou algo relacionado, so não estou conseguindo pegar o nome de outra classe e inserindo nessas atribuições concatenando. Obrigado....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema não está no uso das constantes mas sim na sintaxe da query, que está errada.
Entre SELECT e FROM é necessário indicar o nome das colunas que o select deve conter ou `*` se pretende que contenha todas.

```
String sqlSelectTodosResult = "SELECT * FROM " + DataModel.TABLE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro está na sua string SQL. Você não está passando nenhum parâmetro na cláusula SELECT. Tem que ser:

```
SELECT <coluna1, coluna2, etc> FROM <tabela>
```

ou

```
SELECT * FROM <tabela>
```

para retornar todas as colunas da tabela.